# Java, Intellij IDEA problem Unrecognized option: --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have newly installed

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021
Licensed to XXXXXX
Subscription is active until August 15, 2021.
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.13 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-80-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 3

Kotlin: 212-1.5.10-release-IJ4746.92
Current Desktop: X-Cinnamon
```

I cloned project I work with on other workstation without issues, but cannot start any class with main method and IDEA says:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-5972351880001011455 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2021.2 -Didea.home.path=/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92 -Didea.config.path=/home/pm/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2 -Didea.plugins.path=/home/pm/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2 -Djps.log.dir=/home/pm/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/jbr -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.11 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/pm/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/compile-server/rfg-survey-api_cc70fc05/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea-12426594439704512301-is-running\" -classpath /home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/slf4j.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/platform-api.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/forms_rt.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/util.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/annotations.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/3rd-party.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/jna-platform.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/protobuf-java-3.15.8.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/jna.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/lib/jps-model.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/javaee-appServers-websphere-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/javaee-appServers-weblogic-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/JPA/lib/jps/javaee-jpa-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Grails/lib/groovy-grails-jps.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Grails/lib/groovy-grails-compilerPatch.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar:/home/pm/idea-IU-212.4746.92/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 34781 9f0681bb-da2a-48db-8344-900ddeb29804 /home/pm/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/compile-server
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I found other comment to check Lombok works and I see it is fine.

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Some configuration were rolled over by the update. How to get back to JDK8 :

- Go to File > "Project Structure".
- In the new window, in left tree, choose "Project Settings" > Project
- Among params, look at "Project language level". For me the IJ update had changed it from "8" to "16". Hence the error. Just put it back to "8" and rollll!

Comment: Good to see this solved issues for so many people. Root cause for this is the VM argument which latest JDK understand but older ones don't, newer intellij versions has started using this VM argument. So you have 2 options, First, if you have to use older version of java keep using older intellij Second, update java (your home one - the one which is going to be used for launching Intellij) and then you can use up[graded intellij

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the .idea folder and reimport your project again.  I solved this issue in this way.

Answer (score 1):

For Intellij using Maven, you can go to Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Running Tests and uncheck argLine.

[Disable argLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y616x.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are running the project via Java 1.8 and add the `--add-opens` option to the runner. However Java 1.8 does not support it.

So, the first option is to use Java 11 to run the project, as Java 11 can recognize this VM option.

Another solution is to find a place where `--add-opens` is added and remove it.
Check Run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA (VM options field) and Maven/Gradle configuration files for `argLine` (Maven) and `jvmArgs` (Gradle)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to go into .idea -> workspace.xml and set ALTERNATIVE_JRE_ENABLED="false".

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse:

> Also make sure that in your <kbd>Run</kbd> ->a <kbd>Run Configurations</kbd> (or <kbd>Debug
> Configurations</kbd>) > <kbd>Arguments</kbd> tab for the launch configuration
> you are using doesn't contain this option.

<sub>From Eclipse forum's [Ed Merks' answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1106250&goto=1835811&#msg_1835811).</sub>