# After update IntelliJ to 2021.2 (Community Edition) I couldn't run project - Abnormal build process termination

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, adoptopenjdk

While setting up a new machine, I get the Intellij last version, which is the 2021.2 (Community Edition).

I cloned the project from Git, but I could not execute it. Every time I try to do it, I get the following error message:

```
Abnormal build process termination:
"C:\...\java.exe"
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The app I am trying to run is using adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_302 and **it runs smoothly in another IntelliJ version**.

I already tried to use oracle/jdk1.8.0_301, but the problem persists.

Comment: 1) try to delete the `.idea` folder and reimport your project again. 2) try to use `jdk1.8.0_192` instead. 3) also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558478/8370915) can be related to your issue, please, check.

Comment: I have tried the "delete .idea folder" solution, but it does not worked. I checked the solution in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558478/8370915) and this works for me. 

The problem was related to the "Project Language Level" in Project Settings. Thank you for your reply, @invzbl3.

Answer (score 1):

As @invzbl3 pointed out, the solution of this post below resolved my problem:

[Java, Intellij IDEA problem Unrecognized option: --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554693/java-intellij-idea-problem-unrecognized-option-add-opens-jdk-compiler-com-su).

Posted by [@user16545114](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558478/8370915)

> Some configuration were rolled over by the update. How to get back to JDK8 :
>
> - Go to File > "Project Structure".
> - In the new window, in left tree, choose "Project Settings" > Project
> - Among params, look at "Project language level". For me the IJ update had changed it from "8" to "16". Hence the error. Just put it back to "8" and rollll!